# PHP/MySQL - Counting items within a query

Tags: php, mysql, database, counting

I have the following results for my database table:

[image]

**The Query:**

```
SELECT 
service_titles.user_id, service_titles.slide_id, service_titles.name as title_name ,service_names.name as service_name 
FROM service_names 
INNER JOIN service_titles ON service_names.title_id = service_titles.id
```

So what needs to happen is:

- If the user has 2 unique service titles, then the max number of service_names for that title will be **6**
- If the user has 1 service title, the the max number of service_names for that title will be **16**

I will be using PHP for all of the coding, but I am wondering how I would go about this.  I need a way to count how many unique service_titles there are for that user and slide, and then count how many service items there are for each title.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT service_titles.name)
FROM service_names
INNER JOIN service_titles ON service_names.title_id = service_titles.id
GROUP BY service_titles.user_id, service_titles.slide_id
```

That'll get you the number of distinct title_names for each user_id/slide_id combo.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT service_names.name)
FROM service_names
INNER JOIN service_titles ON service_names.title_id = service_titles.id
GROUP BY service_titles.user_id, service_titles.slide_id
```

... and that's the number of distinct service_names for same. If you want both in one query, you can put both `COUNT`s together, since you're using the same `GROUP BY` regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CASE statement within your query to change the max number of service_names.

See [MySQL CASE statement reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html)

To do this in the SQL itself would be quicker than evaluating it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

To count how many distinct titles you can try:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT name)
FROM service_titles
GROUP BY user_id
```